# mongoimport on localhost:3000 not working properly

Tags: mongodb

I get an error when I try to create the database on localhost:3000 (on which I run my app ) using :

```
mongoimport -h localhost:3000 etc...
```

the error : "Server unreachable"

I don't get that error if I only use localhost and not localhost:3000 in my mongoimport, but it doesn't look like the database is accessible from my app.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary workaround is to add the host param to your mongoimport call, letting mongo know that the host is your own machine (127.0.0.1):

```
mongoimport --host=127.0.0.1
```

Comment: hi thanks for you answer :)  my problem is not connecting to localhost, but connecting to localhost:3000. (I just tried your solution and it gives me the same result as using -h localhost)

Comment: add `--port=3000` at the end, `mongoimport --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3000`

Comment: just tried, it doesn't work, I got the same error message : server unreachable :(.

here is the full command : mongoimport --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3000 --db proto --collection reviews --file 'absolute path' --jsonArray

Comment: whats your mongo version/

Comment: 3.2 
Thanks for helping me, I'm desperate to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below command. Replace the below values accordingly

- dbname  - Database Name
- collectioname - Collection Name
- filename - File Name (Full Path)

  mongoimport --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3000 --db dbname --collection collectioname --file=filename.json

Comment: I use : mongoimport --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3000 --db proto --collection reviews --file 'absolute path' --jsonArray

Comment: Run this command in mongo shell and paste the output here. db.runCommand({whatsmyuri : 1 });

Comment: Thanks again for your help. "you" : "127.0.0.1:52242", "ok" :1 :)

I guess it means that mongoimport will create on 52242 by default. I want to use 3000 because that's what I use for my mean stack app and have no idea how to change that (I am a total beginner regarding MEAN and Mongo)

Comment: I hope you are executing the mongoimport command from mongo shell (i.e. not from the app). Please clarify?

Comment: I use the command line where I cd to the directory where mongoimport is and use mongoimport there.

Comment: Could you please try the below command?
mongoimport --host=127.0.0.1 --port=52242 --db proto --collection reviews --file 'absolute path' --jsonArray

Comment: 'no reachable server'

The only way to make it work is to do it without a port.

Really appreciate the time you spend on my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I wrote this assuming you were using meteor. But I realize you don't mention it. Anyways, here is my input.

You can see the port you need to use by typing this

```
meteor mongo
```

Then you see this message on startup

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.6
connecting to:
127.0.0.1:3001/meteor
```

Port is usually 3001.

Then the import shouldn't be done in the Mongo Shell. If you do it in Mongo Shell you receive an error like that
    SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:15

Instead type this in your terminal

```
mongoimport -h localhost --port 3001 -d meteor -c collectioname --type csv --file /path/to/file.csv --headerline
```